# Color vertices in igraph R or C

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have a network file for two groups, A and B, and I am plotting the network in R using igraph, and I would like the vertices to be colored depending on their group. The vertices are orderered, i.e. 1-50 are  group A and 51-100 are group B. In the others forums a similiar question was asked however in those cases the coloring could be made depending on vertex attributes. In my case the vertices do not have attributes (except for their order). This is is how far I got:

```
g<- read.graph("AdjacencyMatrix.net", format = c("pajek"))
V(g)$color <- ifelse(XXXXX[V(g), 2] == 1, XXXXX<=50, XXXXX>50)
```

where XXXXX stands for the id or number of the vertex in the list.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Also, I am creating the network via igraph C, and I export the file AdjacencyMatrix.net from there. Is there maybe a way to export it with the corresponding attributes from there (i.e. A or B node)?

Comment: Did you try for instance `V(g)$color<-rep(c("blue","red"),each=50)`?